# Isn't there a way to jump between conflicts in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Despite my googling, I can't find a keyboard shortcut (or any shortcut) to jump to the next conflict when you're in viewing a file in *conflict mode* (opening a file marked (C) in the source control panel, where the `Accept Current Change | Accept Incoming Change | etc` menu is shown).

[image: Conflict mode]
Note: This is different than compare mode where adds and dels are marked with red and green and F7 or the arrows works.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are looking for these commands:

```
// merge-conflict.next
// merge-conflict.previous
```

So you can put something like this in your `keybindings.json` file:

```
{
    "key": "<your key here>",
    "command": "merge-conflict.next"
},
```

Comment: Anyone knows if this can be limited to only when the merge view is focused? I imagine i'd just need to add the `when` parameter, but not sure how that view is called internally in vscode.

Comment: `textCompareEditorVisible` is the diff view. But conflicts can appear in any editor, not just the diff view. You can see other when clause contexts here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts

Comment: These only operate on the current file, which is not very useful.

Comment: You can add when clause of `mergeConflictsCount > 0` and use a command (like `Alt`+`F5` ) which is already used somewhere else.

Answer (score 19):

Search for "HEAD" and use F3 to move to next conflict and Shift+F3 for previous conflict !

Comment: Whilst technically correct: that wasn't what the question was asking. And it's a sub-optimal solution

Comment: @GeorgeWL I agree that this post doesn't answer what the question was asking, but it looks to me "simple & stupid" enough to like it. :-)

Comment: @yaobin anyway myself I think it absolutely does answer what the question was asking! "Isn't there a way to jump between conflicts in VSCode?"--how does this very nice bit of lateral thinking not answer that? :)

Comment: Not 100%, but good trick!

Answer (score 10):

To summarize the other answers, there are two good ways to do it:

- Just use the [search functionality](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_find-and-replace), and search for a large number of `>` or `<`, e.g. `>>>>>`. Then use <kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (or <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) for faster navigation to the next/previous conflict.
- [Add key bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization) for the respective commands. The ones that were originally added by Microsoft [and then removed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/1de69f4d8d79f370d22f6720b54b7f4a140c60ca) are actually good and it seems they don't conflict with the default schema, at least on Windows:

```json
{   
  "command": "merge-conflict.next", 
  "when": "editorTextFocus",    
  "key": "alt+m down"   
},  
{   
  "command": "merge-conflict.previous", 
  "when": "editorTextFocus",    
  "key": "alt+m up" 
},  
{   
  "command": "merge-conflict.accept.selection", 
  "when": "editorTextFocus",    
  "key": "alt+m enter"  
},  
{   
  "command": "merge-conflict.accept.current",   
  "when": "editorTextFocus",    
  "key": "alt+m 1"  
},  
{   
  "command": "merge-conflict.accept.incoming",  
  "when": "editorTextFocus",    
  "key": "alt+m 2"  
},  
{   
  "command": "merge-conflict.accept.both",  
  "when": "editorTextFocus",    
  "key": "alt+m 3"  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

VS Code used to provide keyboard shortcuts, but they were removed. You can restore them yourself though, just copy them from here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/1de69f4d8d79f370d22f6720b54b7f4a140c60ca.

Comment: they still exist, they just moved them

Comment: Moved them where?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Commands still exist, just there is no key bindings by default.

Comment: That's right, I never said the commands didn't exist, just that the keyboard shortcuts were removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in options under the `Go` menu for `Next Problem` (keyboard shortcut F8) and `Previous Problem` (keyboard shortcut Shift + F8).

I use the GitLens plugin and this works like a charm with no need to create custom keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

For mac I use this:

`Users/{USER}/Libary/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json`

```json
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "merge-conflict.next",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
]
```

A nice command for mac to go to the next merge conflict in your current file :)

Answer (score 0):

## `merge.goToNextUnhandledConflict`

In vscode 2013, in Merge Editor, this is the flag needed:

```
{
    "key": "alt+f5",
    "command": "merge.goToNextUnhandledConflict"
},
```