# How do show git conflicts as diff using VsCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I use VSCode all is good till I try to diff a conflict in a rebase. In IJ I would just `right click > git > show conflicts`.

I can't find a equivalent VSCode extension, can someone point me in the correct direction? How do I show rebase conflicts in VsCode?

Comment: Does this help you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-resolve-conflicts?view=vs-2022

Comment: open the file that has the conflict and the conflict resolve mode is enabled

Comment: @Vini lots to digest there apparently no just a right click sub menu :-P. I will look into it tomorrow and confirm that will work some of the screenshots look promising like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/media/vs-2022/git-conflicts-vertical-view.png?view=vs-2022

Comment: Also I like to use the terminal for most things so I only switch once the conflict lines are created

Comment: Please check this link if this helps
[resolve merge conflicts with git in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216541/visual-studio-code-how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-with-git)